# Sharepoint doesn't recognize credentials on server browser

Tags: 2013, front-end, server, application-server

Something weird happens. When I try to connect to central administration from sharepoint application server it asks me about credentials. I try to log in with farm administrator permissions, but it doesn't let me log in.

When I try to login to the central administration from a local computer or the front end web service server using the same account, I am able to login. The problem continues with my web front end server also when I try to login in one of the sites it tells me to input credentials (again sp farm admin) and it doesn't work. When I try to login to the site from a local computer or the application server using the same account, I am able to login.

I know I can access the setting using other computers, but I wonder why this happens.

Comment: I am using SP2013 and Windows server 2012 r2

Comment: http://www.harbar.net/archive/2009/07/02/disableloopbackcheck-amp-sharepoint-what-every-admin-and-developer-should-know.aspx

Comment: It's a security feature.

Comment: As already pointed out - DisableLoopbackCheck will solve this.

Comment: And in addition, DO NOT disable it in your production environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a security feature from Microsoft, which are explained in detail here:

[DisableLoopbackCheck & SharePoint: What every admin and developer should know.](http://www.harbar.net/archive/2009/07/02/disableloopbackcheck-amp-sharepoint-what-every-admin-and-developer-should-know.aspx)

It can sure be annoying but Microsoft did put it there for a reason. However, if you are on a development or staging environment you could disable it. But never ever do it in a production farm as it's there to keep your farm a little bit more safe.

Here's a easy guide about how you disable it.

[DisableLoopbackCheck. Lets do it the right way](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepoint_foxhole/archive/2010/06/21/disableloopbackcheck-lets-do-it-the-right-way.aspx)

Comment: Or, if you need to crawl from the server itself, add the URL to the exclude link as explained in harbar link above